# Should I be using a Matrix to scale a Bitmap to screen size?

Tags: android, bitmap, screen-resolution

When supporting multiple screen sizes in Android, and having to draw my custom `View` s programmically, is using a `Matrix` to scale a `Bitmap` an efficient way of ensuring that it looks OK for the screen res? Is/isn't this a best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Matrix and Bitmaps will probably work too, but you will have to do the same calculations for resizing over and over again, which is unnecessary and, if done for many images at once, will slow down the user interface. Do it once, create the resources, and be done with it.

Matrix and Bitmaps are used for on the fly bitmap transformations.

Comment: How do I define a bitmap width in dpi programmically though?